# h264 or mp4 with mediaelement.js

Tags: video, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

I've been using the mediaelement.js(http://mediaelementjs.com/)  for our site. I've noticed that I have to convert all the mp4 videos with the codec h264 . If I use the code mpeg-4 for my mp4 video the audio is ok but the video is black.

any idea why is that ?

thanks.

Comment: mp4 is a container format - H264 is a video codec, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

MEJS requires h264 for .mp4 formatted files.